# solving the differential equation : $y' = \sqrt{4x+2y+1}$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I tried solving the differential equation :

$$y' = \sqrt{4x+2y+1}$$

but I really have no direction as to how to solve it. The fact both $x$ and $y$ are under the same root makes for difficulty when solving, since there seems to be no way to separate the two variables. Ideas?

Comment: Maybe make substitution $u = y + 2x$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$y' = \sqrt{4x+2y+1}$$
substitute $z=4x+2y+1$
$$z=4x+2y+1 \implies z'=4+2y' \implies y'=(z'-4)/2$$
$$z'-4=2\sqrt z \implies \int \frac {dz}{\sqrt z+2}=2x+K$$
Then substitute again $u=\sqrt z$ and solve:
$$\int \frac {2udu}{u+1}=2x+K$$

---

Or substitute  $z^2=4x+2y+1 \implies zz'=2+y'$
And solve the seperable equation 
$$zz'-2=z \implies \int \frac {zdz}{z+2}=x+K$$

Comment: Thanks, that was informative

Comment: yw @Bak1139 .....

Answer (score 1):

Substitute $$u(x)=4x+2y(x)$$ then you will get
$$\frac{du(x)}{dx}=2\left(\sqrt{u(x)+1}+2\right)$$